# How to wrap python instance methods at runtime

Tags: python, logging, dynamic, metaprogramming, wrapper

I want to log debug information when calls are made in some class. The logged data is:

- function name
- stack trace of where the function was called from
- time it took the function to execute
- args and kwargs passed to the function

I want the wrapper to be fairly generic. At the same time, the wrapping should take place at run time. I've made the following wrapper class that logs the information and delegates the call to the original instance.

```
import datetime
import traceback
from functools import partial

from logging_module import db_log


class BaseWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self._item = item

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._item, attr)


class DBLogWrapper(BaseWrapper):

    @staticmethod
    def _time_method(method):
        name = "{0}.{1}.{2}".format(
            method.im_class.__module__,
            method.im_class.__name__,
            method.__name__
        )

        def timed_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            begin = datetime.datetime.now()
            return_val = method.im_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            end = datetime.datetime.now()

            trace = traceback.format_stack()

            db_log(
                name,
                begin,
                end,
                info={
                    'args': args,
                    'kwargs': kwargs,
                    'trace': trace
                }
            )
            return return_val

        return timed_method

    def __init__(self, item, methods):
        super(DBLogWrapper, self).__init__(item)
        for method in methods:
            class_method = getattr(item, method)
            wrapped_method = DBLogWrapper._time_method(class_method)
            wrapped_method = partial(wrapped_method, self._item)
            setattr(self, method, wrapped_method)
```

Example Usage:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def hello(self, greeting):
        print greeting

    def goodbye(self):
        print 'Good Bye'

a = MyClass()

if DEBUG:
    a = DBLogWrapper(a, ['hello'])

a.hello()
a.goodbye()
```

In this case the call to `hello` would be logged, but the call to `goodbye` would not.

However, this seems to be overkill for a task which seems like it should be simple. I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the above code or an entirely different way to go about it.

Comment: What's so overkill about it?

Comment: The entire solution seems convoluted to me. Using a partial inside a delegating wrapper to make instance methods work as intended. Just feels a little too hacky

Comment: Why don't you simply write a decorator and apply it to the methods that you want traced? I think it's simpler and clearer.

Comment: Well time it is already essentially a decorator. However, I don't want to just decorate the class methods for a few reasons. First, because I don't have access to the methods I want traced. They're defined in a 3rd party module. Second, because I want these decorators to be applied at run-time based on some flag. I don't want them on all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing too much work. You don't need `partial` at all. Just define `timed_method` without the `self` parameter and call `method` directly:

```
import datetime
import traceback
from functools import partial

def db_log(*args, **kwargs): print args, kwargs # Mock


class BaseWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self._instance = instance

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._instance, attr)


class DBLogWrapper(BaseWrapper):

    @staticmethod
    def _time_method(method):
        name = "{0}.{1}.{2}".format(
            method.im_class.__module__,
            method.im_class.__name__,
            method.__name__
        )

        def timed_method(*args, **kwargs):
            begin = datetime.datetime.now()
            return_val = method(*args, **kwargs)
            end = datetime.datetime.now()

            trace = traceback.format_stack()

            db_log(
                name,
                begin,
                end,
                info={
                    'args': args,
                    'kwargs': kwargs,
                    'trace': trace
                }
            )
            return return_val

        return timed_method

    def __init__(self, instance, methods):
        super(DBLogWrapper, self).__init__(instance)
        for method in methods:
            class_method = getattr(instance, method)
            wrapped_method = DBLogWrapper._time_method(class_method)
            setattr(self, method, wrapped_method)
```

Output:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a = prova.DBLogWrapper(a, ['hello'])
>>> a.hello()
A
('__main__.MyClass.hello', datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 17, 20, 48, 26, 478023), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 17, 20, 48, 26, 478071)) {'info': {'args': (), 'trace': ['  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>\n', '  File "prova.py", line 31, in timed_method\n    trace = traceback.format_stack()\n'], 'kwargs': {}}}
>>> a.goodbye()
B
```

Anyway maybe you may use some `__getattr__` magic instead, for example:

```
class DBLogWrapper2(BaseWrapper):

    def __init__(self, instance, methods):
        super(DBLogWrapper, self).__init__(instance)

        self._methods = methods

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in methods:
            return getattr(self._instance, attr)

        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.timed_method(getattr(self._item, attr),
                                     *args, **kwargs)
        return f

    def timed_method(method, *args, **kwargs):
        begin = datetime.datetime.now()
        return_val = method(*args, **kwargs)
        end = datetime.datetime.now()

        trace = traceback.format_stack()

        db_log(name,
            begin,
            end,
            info={
                'args': args,
                'kwargs': kwargs,
                'trace': trace
            }
        )
        return return_val
```

Comment: Ahhh method is already bound to the item! Awesome this cleans it up a bit. As for the __getattr__ magic, I wanted to try to avoid creating the timed method every time it's called. I guess I could make it lazy and store the wrapped methods in self.__dict__ after they're created. Either way this helps a lot. Thanks

Comment: @Drover Exactly. Methods are defined using getters so that, if you access them from the class they are not bound, but acceing them through an instance bounds the `self` parameter. Read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the above answer. You also don't need to return the instance, which was important in my case because I didn't have access to where it was being used.

```
def method_wrapper(method):
    def method_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Wrapper Code: ', end='')
        return_val = method(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_val

    return method_wrap

def wrap_it(wrapper, instance, method):
    class_method = getattr(instance, method)
    wrapped_method = wrapper(class_method)
    setattr(instance, method, wrapped_method)

class MyClass:

    def hello(self, greeting):
        print(greeting)

    def goodbye(self):
        print('Good Bye')

a = MyClass()

wrap_it(method_wrapper, a, 'hello')

a.hello('hi')
a.goodbye()
```